# octave: how to do logical indexing for cell array

Tags: arrays, indexing, cell, octave

In octave, I have a cell

```
a={{1,'abc',3.5}, {2,'abc',4.5},{3,'def',5.4}}
```

I want to do logical indexing similar to doing it as matrix

Something like

```
a(:,3} =='abc'
```

should produce an array of

```
[1, 1, 0]
```

Basically, I want to produce a new cell array that only has points that have 'abc', so it should reduce to

```
b=a={{1,'abc',3.5}, {2,'abc',4.5}}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a={{1,'abc',3.5}, {2,'abc',4.5},{3,'def',5.4}}
arg = 'abc'

res = cellfun(@(x) ismember(1, strcmp(x, arg)), a)
```

cellfun applies given function to every element of an cell array: 
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html

as pointed in the first link '@(x) creates an anonymous function'

this post shows how to find if a string is in cell array of mixed type:
[Find string in cell array with elements of different types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957949/find-string-in-cell-array-with-elements-of-different-types)

in this case one element of the given cell array is a cell array itself so that is what x will hold.

x is {1,'abc',3.5} -> strcmp(x, arg) is {0, 1, 0} -> ismember(1, {0, 1, 0}) evaluates to 1

x is {2,'abc',4.5} -> strcmp(x, arg) is {0, 1, 0} -> ismember(1, {0, 1, 0}) evaluates to 1

x is {3,'def',5.4} -> strcmp(x, arg) is {0, 0, 0} -> ismember(1, {0, 0, 0}) evaluates to 0

so res contains {1, 1, 0}