# Find index of element in cell array of matrices

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I want to find the index(that's in row and column) of a specific matrix in a cell array of matrices, for example if I have

```
A = [2 3;4 1]
```

and

```
B = {[2 2;1 1] [2 3;4 1] [1 1;1 1]}
```

then I want to return `2`(because `B{2}==A`).

I want to solve this without `for`, although I don't have to, the cell array is basically small, but I want to do it without `for` anyway.

I searched for this and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11957949/find-string-in-cell-array-with-elements-of-different-types) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061344/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-cell-array-in-matlab) on SO but their solution only work for strings which I don't have here.

So how to solve this without `for`-loop ?

### Note

`A` is an ordinary matrix not a single element cell array, `B` is a cell array of matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- Use [`cellfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with [`isequal`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) to test each element of `B` for equality:

  ```
  find(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,A), B))
  ```
- If *all matrices have the same size*: concatenate into a 3D array (or better yet, use a 3D array from the beginning), and use [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for the comparison:

  ```
  find(all(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, cat(3, B{:})),1),2))
  ```

Comment: @niceman They work. Both. With the example you provided. Paste this in Matlab command line: `A=[2 3;4 1]; B={[2 2;1 1] [2 3;4 1] [1 1;1 1]}; find(cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,A), B)), find(all(all(bsxfun(@eq, A, cat(3, B{:})),1),2))`. Both solutions return `2`

Comment: silly me, I confused A with B :), anyway the second is way much faster

Comment: @niceman For greater speed, store the matrices directly as a 3D array, not as a cell array of matrices. That way you avoid using `cat`